# SageMaker Pipeline: TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'ParameterString'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am writing a SageMaker Pipeline and I want to pass the preprocessing script name as input to the pipeline.

```
data_preprocessing_script = ParameterString(
        name="DataPreProcessingScript", default_value='',
        )
```

I have the following code for preprocessing -

```
    sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(
        framework_version=sklearn_framework_version,
        instance_type=processing_instance_type,
        instance_count=processing_instance_count,
        base_job_name=f"PreProcess-{base_job_prefix}",
        volume_size_in_gb=10,
        sagemaker_session=pipeline_session,
        role=role,
        tags=tags
    )

    step_args = sklearn_processor.run(
        code=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, data_preprocessing_script),
        inputs=[
            ProcessingInput(input_name="raw_input_data",
```

With `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, data_preprocessing_script)` the pipeline is failing with

```
TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'ParameterString'
```

If I pass the path/filename - preprocessing.py - instead of the data_preprocessing_script (ParameterString) then it works fine.

```
code=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'preprocessing/xxx_preprocessing.py')
```

How can I parameterize the sagemaker pipeline to take pre-processing script filename as input instead of hard-cording the filename.